# reindex (remapping) column's value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
 groupID        date_time         value     member     Session
     23       2013-10-09 09:00:00    664639   Jerome        2607
     23       2013-10-09 09:05:00    197290   Hence         2608
     35       2013-10-09 09:10:00    470186     Ann         2608
     35       2013-10-09 09:15:00    181314   Mikka         2608
     35       2013-10-09 09:20:00    969427  Cristy         2609
     37       2013-10-09 09:25:00    261473   James         2609
     37       2013-10-09 09:30:00    3698     Oliver        2609
```

So the goal I would like that instead of `2607` I have `1`, instead of `2608` I have `2` etc, i.e. to make kind of reindexing or maybe mapping

```
       groupID        date_time         value     member     Session
         23       2013-10-09 09:00:00    664639   Jerome        1
         23       2013-10-09 09:05:00    197290   Hence         2
         35       2013-10-09 09:10:00    470186     Ann         2
         35       2013-10-09 09:15:00    181314   Mikka         2
         35       2013-10-09 09:20:00    969427  Cristy         3
         37       2013-10-09 09:25:00    261473   James         3
         37       2013-10-09 09:30:00    3698     Oliver        3
```

searching on `reindexing` haven't given desired results, so your advices will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can just do:

```
df['Session'] -= 2606
```

Seeing as it looks like your values are increasing in a positive manner.

Or you could define a dict and remap

```
session_vals = df['Session'].unique()
d = dict(zip(session_vals, np.arange(1, len(session_vals) + 1)))

df['Session'] = df['Session'].map(d)
```

Another method is to use [`pd.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html)

```
In [233]:
df['Session'] = pd.factorize(df['Session'])[0] + 1
df

Out[233]:
   groupID           date_time   value  member  Session
0       23 2013-10-09 09:00:00  664639  Jerome        1
1       23 2013-10-09 09:05:00  197290   Hence        2
2       35 2013-10-09 09:10:00  470186     Ann        2
3       35 2013-10-09 09:15:00  181314   Mikka        2
4       35 2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy        3
5       37 2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473   James        3
6       37 2013-10-09 09:30:00    3698  Oliver        3
```

Comment: thanks, EdChum, it works! btw, maybe you could look at this question (especially cause it uses the method you proposed early, but has troubles on ```groupby``` objects!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541280/apply-and-transform-dont-work-for-groupby-object?noredirect=1#comment54863991_33541280

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Session'] = np.unique(df['Session'], return_inverse=True)[1]
```

unique sessions will be numbered starting at 0.

Comment: strangely it starts the sessions with ```3```

Comment: perhaps the first session in your column is ``3``, but the smallest number in the column will be ``0``. The unique labels will be in the sorted order of the inputs.

Comment: Maybe add 1 to match the desired output `np.unique(df['Session'], return_inverse=True)[1] + 1`